# Unable to download Hyperledger Fabric platform-specific binaries on Windows 10

Tags: curl, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am following the steps mentioned at http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/samples.html#binaries

I have installed all the prerequisites but when I try execute the given curl command I keep getting the following error :

***$ curl -sSL https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s 1.1.0
bash: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
bash: line 1:`'***

I have the following curl version:

$ curl --version
curl 7.49.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) libcurl/7.49.1 OpenSSL/1.0.2h zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.32 libssh2/1.7.0 nghttp2/1.11.1 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: IDN IPv6 Largefile SSPI Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM SSL libz TLS-SRP HTTP2 Metalink

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the correct URL. That github URL will give you the source of the HTML page that displays the content of the bootstrap script rather the script itself. You can see that if instead of piping the result into bash you look at what you get from the curl command with something such as:

$ curl -sSL https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | less

So, instead try:

$ curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s 1.1.0